# Angular2 Webpack and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, angular

I've installed Angular 2 Webpack which includes a sample app and demonstrates routing. What I want to look into is using Angular2 for the front end routing but to the use ExpressJS for a RESTful API backend, but on the same server i.e.

http://localhost:3000/#/    will serve the front end in Angular
http://localhost:3000/api   will serve the back end API in Express

If I create a api/index.html I can see this shows the api home page but I haven't got a clue how to create the 'app.js' for express to get the express routing working.

I appreciate I could easily do it by running two instances but I was trying to keep it all self contained.

Regards

Comment: The [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) are pretty straightforward for routing. You might want to check out [express generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) for easier scaffolding of your server.

Comment: Use https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli article, I found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do it on the same port so I went with placing this in config/webpack.common.js. (I had thought I would need to start a separate 'npm' process for the API but clearly not!)

```js
var express = require('express');
var app2 = express();

app2.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('API');
});

app2.listen(3001, function () {
});
```